# Hyperledger Fabric UNKNOWN: identity expired issue Channel Sending proposal with transaction failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

```
Channel Channel{id: 3, name: mychannel} Sending proposal with transaction: xxxxxxx to Peer{ id: 1, name: peer0.org1.example.com, channelName: mychannel, url: grpc://xxxxxx} failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNKNOWN, description=**identity expired**, cause=null}


Channel mychannel failed proposal on peer peer0.org1.example.com

org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer peer0.org1.example.com.  Status FAILURE, details: Channel Channel{id: 3, name: mychannel} Sending proposal with transaction: xxxxxxxx to Peer{ id: 1, name: peer0.org1.example.com, channelName: mychannel, url: grpc://xxxx} failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNKNOWN, description=identity expired, cause=null}

java.lang.Exception: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: identity expired
```

I am running IBM’s blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk. After java-sdk 1.4.1 is used, there is no problem in creating a channel, instantiating the chaincode, and registering CA users. This problem occurs when I invoke the chaincode is executed.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Appears that the certificate for your identity has expired

Comment: How can we renew identity?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the identity of your client is expired,you should make sure that the identity of the client corresponds to the netWork.